# How to create sub-collections using Firebase Transactions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

when my user is created, then I run Transactions (functions.auth.user().onCreate()) to create few documents in some collections. But now, additionally, I need to create a path like this:

/collection1/{uid}/subcol1/{id}/subcol2/

"collections", "subcol1", "subcol2" should have one document inside. How can I do this? First of all, I don't know how to add sub-collection to the created collections document ({uid}). I have something like this:

```
const ref = admin.firestore().doc(`collection1/${event.uid}`);

return admin.firestore().runTransaction(async (transaction) => {
  const snapshot = await transaction.get(ref);

  if (!ref.exists) {
    transaction.set(
      snapshot,
      {
        fields: {
          field1: 0,
          field2: 0,
        },
      },
      { merge: true }
    );
  }
});
```

How should I add sub-collections to have a path like above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no special code required to create a subcollection.  Collections and subcollections are automatically created when the first document is added to them, and removed when last document is deleted.  It's the same for transactions as well as normal writes.

This means that you actually need to write a document in your transaction in order for the subcollection to appear. You can do that just like you are now with `transaction.set()`.  All you have to do is build a reference to the document just like your `ref`, and provide the data.

```
const ref2 = admin.firestore()
    .collection("collection1").
    .doc(event.uid)
    .collection("your-subcollection")
    .doc("your-document);
transaction.set(ref2, { your: data });
```

As you can see, it's really no different than what you're doing now.

Comment: Nice, really simple. Thx!